# Plotting audio spectrogram in python

Tags: python, audio, machine-learning, spectrogram

I currently have a few thousand audio clips that I need to classify with machine learning.

After some digging I found that if you do a short time fourier transform on the audio, it turns into a 2 dimensional image so I can use various image classification algorithms on these images instead of the audio files themselves.

To this end I found a [python package](https://github.com/audiolabs/stft) that does the STFT and all I need is to plot it so I can get the images. For plotting I found [this github repo](https://gist.github.com/endolith/2784026) very useful.

Finally my code ended up as this:

```
import stft    
import scipy
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab

def save_stft_image(source_filename, destination_filename):
    fs, audio = wav.read(source_filename)
    X = stft.spectrogram(audio)

    print X.shape    

    fig = pylab.figure()    
    ax = pylab.Axes(fig, [0,0,1,1])    
    ax.set_axis_off()
    fig.add_axes(ax)      
    pylab.imshow(scipy.absolute(X[:][:][0].T), origin='lower', aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest')
    pylab.savefig(destination_filename)

save_stft_image("Example.wav","Example.png")
```

And output is:
[image]

The code works, however I observed that when `print X.shape` line executes I get `(513L, 943L, 2L)`. So the result is 3 dimensional. So when I only write `X[:][:][0]` or `X[:][:][1]` I get an image.

I keep reading this "redundancy" STFT has, that you can remove the half because you would not need it. Is that 3rd dimension that redundancy or am I doing something very wrong here? If so how do I properly plot it?

Thank you.

Edit:
So the new code and output is:

```
import stft
import os
import scipy
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab

def save_stft_image(source_filename, destination_filename):
    fs, audio = wav.read(source_filename)
    audio = scipy.mean(audio, axis = 1)
    X = stft.spectrogram(audio)

    print X.shape    

    fig = pylab.figure()    
    ax = pylab.Axes(fig, [0,0,1,1])    
    ax.set_axis_off()
    fig.add_axes(ax)      
    pylab.imshow(scipy.absolute(X.T), origin='lower', aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest')
    pylab.savefig(destination_filename)

save_stft_image("Example.wav","Example.png")
```

[image]

On the left I get an almost invisible column of colors. The sounds I am working on are respiratory sounds, so they have very low frequencies. Maybe that's why the visualization is a very thin column of colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an stereo audio file? So `X[:][:][0]` and `X[:][:][1]` correspond to each channel.

You can convert multichannel to mono by `scipy.mean(audio, axis=1)`.